# How to distinguish between procedures and syntax in a macro?

Tags: macros, racket, metaprogramming

It is possible to write a macro, which performs a 1-ary evaluation:

```
(define-syntax 1ary
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (1ary arg))
     (let ((1ary-val 1ary)
           (arg-val  arg))
       (1ary-val arg-val)))))

(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
(1ary (inc 0))
```

But it does not work with syntax:

```
(1ary (quote 0))
```

How to change the macro such that it works for syntax?

**Update**

Another example:

```
#lang racket

(define (counter c)
  (lambda ()
    (set! c (+ c 1))
    c))

(define (inc x) (+ x 1))

(define c (counter 0))
(define-syntax 1ary:1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (1ary arg))
     (let ((arg-val arg))
       (printf "arg-val: ~s\n" arg-val)
       (1ary arg-val)))))

(printf "#1\n")
(1ary:1 (quote (c)))
(1ary:1 (inc (c)))

(set! c (counter 0))
(define-syntax 1ary:2
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (1ary arg))
     (let ((arg-val arg))
       (printf "arg-val: ~s\n" arg-val)
       (1ary arg)))))

(printf "#2\n")
(1ary:2 (quote (c)))
(1ary:2 (inc (c)))
```

It prints:

```
#1
arg-val: 1
'arg-val
arg-val: 2
3
#2
arg-val: 1
'(c)
arg-val: 2
4
```

In the first case the result for the syntax is wrong (`'arg-val`) but the result for the side effect is right (`3`). In the second case the result for the syntax is right (`'(c)`) but the result for the side effect is wrong (`4`). How to get both right?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete description of what you are trying to accomplish? This macro doesn't seem very useful, and it's unclear what "works for syntax" means exactly.

Comment: @PeterWinton When `1ary` is syntax instead of a procedure I want to expand it, before I evaluate it to `1ary-val`.

Comment: The point of  `quote` is to not evaluate its argument, but you're trying to evaluate it anyways?

Comment: @Shawn I try to figure out, when I have to (proc) and when I must not (syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that syntax is not possible to pass as values so you trying to evaluate the operator will fail since `quote` isn't a variable like `inc` is. This will work though:

```
(define-syntax 1ary
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ (op arg))
     (op arg))))
```

Comment: Yes this avoids the problem, but I want to de-structure the expression. I think `syntax-rules` might not be the right tool for this. But I was hoping Racket could have a solution based on `syntax-parse` or a custom transformer or any other way I am not aware of.

Comment: We need a clearer specification to be able to help you. How will you use the de-structuring?

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase I want to display `arg-val`.

Comment: @ceving But if operator is a macro then the arg-val might not be possible to evaluatre. eg. `else` in a `cond` is syntax, but won't evaluate. You can print the syntax by just adding a quote. eg. `(begin (display 'arg) (op arg))`

Answer (score 0):

Is this, perhaps, what you're looking for?

```
(define-syntax 1ary
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ (p a))
     (begin
       (printf "arg: ~s\n" 'a)
       (p a))]))
```

```
> (1ary (quote (c)))
arg: (c)
'(c)
> (1ary (inc (c)))
arg: (c)
2
```

You may also find [`expand`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Expanding_Top-Level_Forms.html) and [`trace-define-syntax`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/debugging.html) useful.